# Need help to find user location in android?

Tags: android, geolocation

I am developing a location based application.I need help for that application

My requirement is

1.Find the user location using GPS

2.If GPS is not available or not enabled means generate the task bar notification

3.If the user doesn't enable GPS up to 5 minutes find the user location using network provider after five minute

4.If both the provider is disabled means get the user's last known location using any of the best provider

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get available location providers, register for location updates with LocationManager:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html

Create status bar notifications:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html